# Create owner drawn menus with C++, 2012-style

Tags: c++, winapi, contextmenu

The goal of my quest is simple -- add icons to my context menu that is displayed through a call to TrackPopupMenu API. But evidently coding for Windows is like paddling with a spoon and there's no easy way of adding icons besides making owner drawn menus. So I did some search that came up with a bunch of C++ code on the subject of owner drawn menus, but so far I can't find any that would work for me. The reason is simple -- the menus it draws look like something that came out from Windows 95... So is there any way to do owner-drawn menus that have default Windows 7 look?

PS. If there's an easier way of adding icons to menu items, say, LoadIcon then ChangeMenuItem to set it, I'd appreciate if someone could show me how, because I'd gladly go with it instead...

**PS2.** OK, it takes way too long for my liking. Why can't I seem to do the simplest task in this OS :( I made a [small test project](http://forums.codeguru.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=30701&d=1354434597) to illustrate the issue. I load the bitmap with my own CreatePARGBBitmapFromIcon method that converts an icon into a PARGB bitmap (as was suggested below) and then displays it in two places: CStatic control (middle of the screen, that looks just fine), and in the menu item (that totally f's it up.) Here's the screenshot from Windows 7 and XP (both look totally different):

[image]

[image]

So guys, seriously, what am I missing here????

**PS3.** Thanks to @DavidHeffernan, I was able to fix it. [Here's the working C++/MFC solution](http://forums.codeguru.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=30707&d=1354594868), here's an [article](http://www.nanoant.com/programming/themed-menus-icons-a-complete-vista-xp-solution) the solution is based on, and here're a couple of screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Just FYI, it took me around 2 days to get this solved -- something that would've taken about 2 minutes on OS X, or iOS ...

And lastly a couple of my favorite quotes from the source article that I totally endorse:

> All those hacks and recipes would be worthless if only there was
>   simple consistent API for making menu item icons. Unfortunately menu
>   icons, something that was always present in Windows and Microsoft
>   applications, never got any decent API, moreover the methods to get
>   those icons working change for every major Windows release, **making us
>   developers wasting our time “porting” our applications to new “shinny”
>   Windows rather than doing something productive**.

and this sums it up nicely:

> **AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARGH! Why is Microsoft filled by
>   idiots???**

Comment: You have three choices for icons AFAIK: replacing the string with an icon, and having icons that show beside it when it's checked or unchecked. See the `MENUITEMINFO` structure for details.

Comment: ASAIK checked or unchecked icons can be only monochrome. So what's the 3rd option?

Comment: You can do owner draw menus which respect the style. Using the theme API. But it's a ruddy awful idea and almost impossible to get right. Only the true greats can expect to succeed. So don't do that. Let the system draw the menus and supply an HBITMAP for the icon. Supply it in the `hbmpItem` field of `MENUITEMINFO`. 32bpp, PARGB. For instance: http://www.nanoant.com/programming/themed-menus-icons-a-complete-vista-xp-solution

Comment: @user843732, All I can find is that it has to be the same size as the default checkmark bitmap.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to avoid. But you see from my understanding of bitmaps -- they can't contain transparency so icons will look "funky". Am I wrong? If they can, how would you create one from an icon?

Comment: @chris: Yeah, but unfortunately that check-mark size is usually 15x15 pix.

Comment: @user843732, I never noticed the question in your second option. By three, I meant three different bitmaps you can use (checked and unchecked being separate), but reflecting on that, the wording would probably make more sense if I said the third is the one you describe in your question.

Comment: Bitmaps can contain transparency. You need 32bpp PARGB bitmaps.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thanks, good news. So how do you create this 32bpp PARGB bitmap? Is it by dealing with DIB sections and "RGBA" bits directly?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I added my own method of loading a PARGB bitmap. Can you check?

Comment: Your menu looks like it is owner drawn. You must have system drawn menus.

Comment: No, it's not. I set that image by calling SetMenuItemInfo() with MIIM_BITMAP mask flag. Can you take a look at the code sample I posted in my edit above?

Comment: The PARGB32 looks wrong on the first image. As for XP, I think you do need owner drawn if you want glyphs with alpha channel in menus.

Comment: David, I know that it looks wrong :) I'm trying to figure out why?

Comment: Most likely you didn't pre-multiply color channels by alpha. If you don't use @David at tagging then I don't get notification.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Why would the exact same bitmap look perfectly anti-aliased in the static control (middle of the screen)?

Comment: Because the menu needs premultiplied alpha and the static control does not.

Comment: There's another difference between Mac and Windows. Your 15 year old Windows code still runs fine today. Not so on the Mac. Remember that you are using the lowest level Windows API. If you picked WPF say you'd have your menus done in 2 minutes also.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan With WPF (or .NET) you need to lug along oodles of dlls and other MS crap. As for OS X, then Objective-C is about that old as well, and is still fully used to develop for that platform... unlike MS, that are trying to "invent" (i.e. copy) "new programming language" with every release of Windows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This article tells you how to do it: http://www.nanoant.com/programming/themed-menus-icons-a-complete-vista-xp-solution

In summary, on XP you should pass HBMMENU_CALLBACK in the hbmpItem field of the MENUITEMINFO struct. This makes your menu owner draw, but you only need to deal with the icon in WM_MEASUREITEM and WM_DRAWITEM.

On Vista and up you put a PARGB32 bitmap (pre-multiplied alpha, 32 bit color depth) in hbmpItem and let the system draw the menu. So, no owner draw on Vista and up. Although the theme API does offer functionality for painting menus, it is fiendishly difficult to get right and there's really no need since you can let the system do it.

Comment: You're the man! I fixed it. The working solution is attached to my original post. Thanks again!